# Multiple Jenkins files in the same repo and same branch for different purposes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to create multiple pipelines on the same repo. For instance, there is the usual build pipeline that is triggered by git. However, there is another pipeline which is for targeted testing on separate hardware that has entirely different constraints on how it is triggered and what it runs. Both of these pipelines function on the same branch.

Would it be incorrect (or even anti-pattern) if I were to create two Jenkins files (say "Jenkins.build", "Jenkins.targettest" ...) on the same branch of the repo?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem as long as it works for you. It's better to have files close to each other, so you can have a look on both.

Comment: You may want to create a single pipeline that will analyze why it's triggered and select hardware and steps accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an anti-pattern as long as those Jenkinsfile have different scopes that are as much unrelated as possible. In long run, the risk of keeping two separate Jenkinsfile is to let duplicated code spread to each one.
For complex projects, I think it's totally ok to have different Jenkinsfile, but usually I would recommend to keep things as simple as possible, and forcing yourself to use only one Jenkinsfile will avoid making mistakes and choices you would regret in the long run.

It's perfectly feasible to only run specific stages depending on the detected file changes (e.g : skip deployment if only internal documentation was updated), or to skip stages depending on the branch names or some conditions.

Comment: Our pipelines will be considerably different. So it simpler and easier to maintain two simple pipelines instead of having one complex pipeline. I will try this approach.